# Ordinal addition not commutative mistake

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, well-orders

Please see below this example from my notes. I basically understand it except for where it defines the function $f$. If I am not mistaken shouldn’t it be $f(\xi):= \xi + n, (\xi \in \omega \setminus n)$ because as $n\leqslant \omega$ then $\xi \in \omega$ could also make $\xi \in n$?

Also on a general note why does it define $f$ for $\xi \in n$ and not $\xi \leqslant n$ and similar for the others?

[image]

Comment: I think the first part of the definition of $f$ should be $\xi\in A$ (rather than $\xi\in n$). The confusion probably comes because $A$ is similar to $n$.

Comment: $\xi \in n $ implies the ordered pair is in $A$ I believe.

Comment: It doesn’t matter if $n=\omega$. If $\xi\in n=\omega$, then $f(\xi)$ has just one definition; it is $f(\xi,0)$ that has a different definition.

Comment: But $n$ is a finite ordinal.

Comment: If $n$ is a finite ordinal, then you cannot have $n=\omega$; you have $n\lt \omega$. But even if $n$ were equal to $\omega$, what is the problem that you believe exists?

Comment: You do understand that the definition of order is $\xi\lt\eta\iff \xi\in\eta$, and $\xi\leq\eta\iff \xi\lt \eta\vee \xi=\eta$, right? “$n$ is finite” means $n\in\omega$, not $n\leq\omega$. That is also why you take $\xi\in n$, not $\xi\leq n$; the element $(n,0)$ is not in $A$.

Comment: Could I say < instead of $\in$?

Comment: For ordinals, that’s the definition: the ordinal $\alpha$ is strictly less than the ordinal $\beta$ if and only if $\alpha\in\beta$. It just so happens that ordinals are transitive, so $x\in\alpha\implies x\subseteq \alpha$, but you can never have equality because ordinals are well-founded. So in fact, $x\in\alpha\implies x\subsetneq \alpha$.